# define a pointer variable to the function in C program

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

If I want to define a pointer variable `p` to point to the function `foo()` defined as below, what should be the exact type of `p`?

```
int *foo(void *arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it more easy you could for the function declaration

```
int *foo(void *arg);
```

define an alias named as for example `Tfoo` that looks the same way as the function declaration itself

```
typedef int *Tfoo(void *);
```

After that to declare a function pointer to the function is very easy. Just write

```
Tfoo *foo_ptr = foo;
```

Otherwise you could write

```
typedef int * (* TFoo_ptr )(void *);

Tfoo_ptr foo_ptr = foo;
```

Or you could write a declaration of the function pointer directly without using the typedef/

```
int * (* foo_ptr )(void *) = foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
typedef int *(*funtion_foo_type)(void *);
```

Comment: Actually, I would suggest that defining a `typedef` for the function signature, that is like the function but with `typedef` before, e.g. `typedef int*foo_type(void*);` then using a *pointer* to that type, i.e. `foo_type* funptr;` is even more readable

Comment: However, this is not a type. This is a type definition operator.

Comment: @KyryloPolezhaiev: `typedef` is not an operator. Syntactically it is a _storage-class specifier_. A `typedef`ed name is an alias for the actual type.

Comment: Sorry, I meant statement. I didn't mean `typedef`, I meant whole string. Tried to avoid confusion, made more confusion (:

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the pointer as the pointer to a function, returning an `int *`, accepting a `void*` argument. You can make it like

```
int * (*p) (void *);
```

and then, you can use

```
p = foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

Bearing in mind the comment of  Kyrylo Polezhaiev, the *type* of p is

```
int*(*)(void*)
```

To declare `p`, you need to insert the name at the correct point in the type:

```
int*(*p)(void*);
```

but it is generally more readable to use an alias:

```
typedef int*(func_t)(void*);
func_t* p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about pointer to function?

First define a pointer to function that takes `void` argumenta and return `int`

```
typedef   int (*Ptrtofun)(void);
```

Now safely can point this to your function.

```
Ptrtofun p;
p = &foo(void);
```

Now you have a ptr `p` to function and can easily use it ..